# Multiplicative inverse of a regular function is regular.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{A}^n_k$ an algebraic set. Let $f:X\to k$ a regular function over $X$ such that $f(x)\neq 0\ \forall x\in X$. Show that $1/f:X\to k$ is also regular over $X$.

Regular means that $f(x)=P(x)\in k[x_1,\dots, x_n]\ \forall x\in X$, and by hypothesis $P(x)\neq 0\ \forall x\in X$. Since $X$ is algebraic, $X=\mathcal{V}(g_1,\dots,g_m)$ with $g_i\in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. Thus, $f\notin\langle g_1,\dots,g_m\rangle$ (the ideal generated by these polynomials).

But from that I don't know how to show that $1/f$ can be expressed as a polynomial on $X$. Any hint?

Comment: $f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in X$ means more than what you say. It says the ideal generated by $f, g_1,\ldots, g_m$ is the polynomial ring. Can you finish the proof now?

Comment: First of all I don't see why is that true.
But assuming it is, then the ideal generated by the $g_i$'s is maximal, and then the ring of regular functions would be a field, containing the inverse of $f$.

Comment: If $<f,g_1,\ldots,g_m>\neq k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$, there is a maximal ideal containing all these. This maximal ideal is a point in $X$, since it contains all the $g_i$s. $f$ is zero at this point, since $f$ too is in the maximal ideal.

Comment: Yes, I've just proved that. But now I think my previous reasoning was wrong, I mean, I'm not convinced that the ideal generated by $\langle g_1,\ldots, g_m\rangle$ is maximal. There could be another polynomial $h\neq f$ such that $\langle h,g_1,\ldots,g_m\rangle \neq k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $X=V(g_1,\ldots, g_m)$. Note that your hypothesis is $X\cap V(P)=\emptyset$,  and you want to prove that there exists a polynomial $h\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ such that $h(x)=\frac{1}{P(x)}$ for all $x\in X$.
From general theory you know that $X\cap V(P)=V(g_1,\ldots,g_m)\cap V(P)=V(g_1,\ldots,g_m,P)$ and hence the hypothesis is equivalent to $V(g_1,\ldots,g_m,P)=\emptyset$. As a consequence of the Hilbert Nullstellensatz one concludes that $\langle g_1,\ldots,g_m,P\rangle=k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$ (for every proper ideal has a zero). In particular, $1=h_1g_1+\ldots+h_mg_m+hP$ for certain polynomials $h,h_1,\ldots,h_m$. Note that this $h$ is the polynomial you were looking for.